# An differential problem is general

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does there exist a differential equation $g(f^{n},f^{n−1},...,f,x)=0$, such that the corresponding equation $g(x_n,x_{n−1},...,x_1,x_0)=0$ has solutions in $C^{n+1}$, but that itself has no solution?

Comment: Why downvote this?

Comment: You should show your work too so that others can figure out at where did you get stuck!